# How to extract/capture streaming url in batch mode?

Tags: batch-file, url, streaming, autoit

in FireFox, if Video DownloadHelper installed, one can get the streaming URL of the current site (if any) eg

```
 www .examplevideo.tv/room1
```

and Video DownloadHelper can tell me the     streaming URL is 
video.examplevideo.tv/live/12345678asdf?id=987654321

However, it is a tedious task if I have many sites need to capture, is there any software can capture in batch mode? i.e. I supply a list of web addresses     and it will return a list of streaming url to me ? Or if such software not exist, can I perform it with AutoIt ? Thanks.

Regds
LAM Chi-fung

Comment: Your question, 'is there any software can capture in batch mode?' is explicitly off-topic here. Use a search engine of alternative site, perhaps even [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE]. @Compo is correct, your post is definitely off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, youtube-dl (https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/ ) is a command line program and with the -g parameter, it can return the streaming link for me. Now I can run it through AutoIt to perform my task.